# How to include documentation from various files into Sphinx/Read The Docs documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, read-the-docs

I just can't seem to figure that out. I have this kind of library basically (simplified):

```
Library
 |doc
 | scripts
   | make
     | makefiles
   | R
     | R scripts
   | snakemake
     | snakefiles
 | config
```

I want comments (docstring or some other format) from certain files included in my documentation: config files, scripts, snakefile... However I'm beginning with Sphinx and Read The Docs, and I couldn't find help with google whatsoever. Most things I found assume people working on python modules with specific structure it seems.

Basically I would like to be able to write this kind of things in my doc:

```
.. include:: <docstring from path/to/my/file>
```

and have the comments display properly.

Is this even possible though?... Thanks for help!

Comment: Sphinx can automatically document docstrings of Python modules, but only Python. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html Sorry, I don't know of any other supported languages.